# How to create a new file and write data to it

Tags: php

Hello people I have created a script that creates a new file in the folder users in the server directory the problem cones when coding it here is the code please tell me all the possible solutions

the statement to create the file:

```
    $my_file ="users/$fname.$lname.php";
    $handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
```

the statement to write the data to the file:

```
   $my_file = "users/$fname.$lname.php";
   $handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);

   $data = 'the PHP code goes here';

   fwrite($handle, $data);
```

I want to write this piece of code

```
     <?php
     include('connect.php');
     $result =mysql_query('SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE email = "'.   mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']) . '"')or  trigger_error(mysql_error());
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
     echo '<div id="gender_container">'.
        '<div id="gender_title">Gender:</div>'.
        '<div id="gender_name">'.$row['gender'].'</div>'.
        '</div>'.
        '<div id="email_container">'.
        '<div id="email_title">E-mail:</div>'.
        '<div id="user_email">'.$row['email'].'</div>'.
        '</div>';
     }
     ?>
```

how do I do it?

Comment: Just put that text in the $data variable. Also, you want to fclose($handle) when done.

Comment: I don't know why you would want to do this. Perhaps it's better to create a template page that changes with the values you pass to it. Doing it this way will make it wildly difficult to troubleshoot. And also, `mysql_*` is deprecated.

Comment: please could you type the fix as a answer I am kind of a newbie in php

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it.

Comment: the purpose of this code is to create a new file for each and every user registered in the database

Comment: What errors did you got?

Comment: What is the problem with $data = '<?php ....?>'? If you cannot explain why you cannot put that text in the string, we cannot tell you how to do it.

Comment: *"the purpose of this code is to create a new file for each and every user registered in the database"* - Why in god's name would you do such a thing?!

Comment: to allow other people to view someone else profile

Comment: the problem with $data = '<?php ....?>' is that it shows Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'connect' (T_STRING)

Comment: Ever heard of writing something like `mysite.com/profile.php?user=yasin`?!

Comment: no this is new for me how do i do it

Comment: Please read more PHP tutorials/books/take a lesson. Passing parameters via the URL and using those to display certain data is the **bare basic principle** on which most PHP sites operate.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use the file_put_contents() method instead this "heavy" code.

And, you should be able to do it this way:

```
<?php
$data = "<?php echo "php code goes here"; ?>";
file_put_contents($filename, $data) or die("ERROR at line:".__LINE__);
?>
```